# Función Change() solo funciona loggeado como Admin

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo una duda la cual no he podido responder y me gustaría saber si me pueden ayudar.
Resulta que estoy realizado un software utilizando el framework Laravel, allí tengo una vista para la creación de elementos dentro del sistema llamada *create.blade.php* en ella tengo 2 campos de formulario de tipo *select picker* los cuales utilizo dinámicamente.

El primero se llama *Clase elemento* y el segundo *Subclase elemento*, la idea principal es que cuando el usuario seleccione una de las clases en el apartado de las subclases se desplieguen solamente aquellas subclases pertenecientes a esa clase guardadas en la base de datos. Para esto he realizado el siguiente código en JS.

```js
<script>
            $("#claseElemento").change(function (event) {
                $.get("create/" + event.target.value + "", function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#subClaseElemento").empty();
                    $("#subClaseElemento").append("<option value ='#' disabled selected>Seleccionar...</option>");
                    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        $("#subClaseElemento").append("<option value =' " + response[i].codSubClaseElemento + " '> " + response[i].nombreSubClase + " </option>");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Los campos del formulario son los siguientes:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="clase_codClase"> Clase Elemento</label>
                                <div class="select">
                                    <select name="clase_codClase" class="form-control" id="claseElemento" required>
                                        <option value="#" selected disabled>Seleccionar...</option>
                                        @foreach($clases as $ce)
                                            <option value="{{ $ce->codClaseElemento }}">{{ $ce->nombreClase }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="subClase_codSubClase">Sub Clase Elemento</label>
                                <div class="select">
                                    <select name="subClase_codSubClase" class="form-control" id="subClaseElemento"
                                            required>
                                        <option value="#" selected disabled>Seleccionar...</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Lo que no he podido resolver es lo siguiente: cuando estoy logueado como administrador dentro del sistema, la función se ejecuta con normalidad y la respuesta en la línea *console.log* es el array que quiero que muestre el campo subclases. Pero al estar logueado como usuario normal, en la consola me muestra una página completa en HTML y en en el campo subclases sale un listado *undefined*.

Les agradezco mucho si me pueden colaborar, ya que no he podido resolverlo y no tengo ni idea de que ocurre.

Comment: Tu problema no está en el Javascript, viene desde PHP. Seguramente tienes una restricción de accesos o middlewares que están rechazando la solicitud de un usuario normal. Esto hace que el `response` no sea un JSON y por tanto no existan los índices que necesitas para llenar el `select` agrega tu código de PHP

Answer (score 0):

En el controller que hace la consulta, revisa que la function `__construct()` no tenga el middleware `auth`, si lo tiene solo aceptara solicitudes de usuarios loggeados, de ser asi lleva tu solicitud a otro controller que no tenga este middleware